# How do I change my username on this site?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I cant seem to find any way of changing my user default name, Any Help?

Comment: So you found out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

click on your username in the top frame.

Next, in the right hand corner press "edit".

The form opens.

Comment: Oh, duh. Now i feel stupid, haha, thanks for your help.

Comment: You will be forgiven when you accept the answer :-)